# Timeout MVC website after period of inactivity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, timeout, session-cookies, setcookie

I'm trying to timeout my MVC site after a period of inactivity.

I've tried numerous things but none seem to work. I've tried the following:

using the CookieAuthenticationOptions class

```
  app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
  {
      ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
      AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
      LoginPath = new PathString("/xxx")
   });
```

using forms authentication element in the web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms" >
    <forms loginUrl="~/xxxx"  timeout="1"/>
</authentication>
```

and also using the sessionState within the config file:

```
<sessionState timeout="1"/>
```

But none of these seem to work.

What am I missing and which is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

First, you're conflating two concepts here: session timeout and authentication timeout. In other words, there's no such thing as a "website timeout"; you need to figure out what you're actually trying to control here. Next, session timeouts are *sliding*, so as long as the user is actively using the website, their session will never timeout. Authentication timeouts are absolute, though, so after the specified time has passed, the user will be logged out, regardless of whether they are actively using the site or not.

As far as authentication timeouts go, you're actually conflating two concepts here as well: Identity and Membership (forms authentication). The first bit of code you have is how the authentication timeout is controlled in ASP.NET Identity, while the second piece of code is how you control that with ASP.NET Membership. The two are mutually exclusive and obviously need to match with the actual authentication mechanism your project is utilizing.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So I'm trying to do a mix of both. I'm using FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie and Response.SetCookie to pass in a HttpCookie that expires after say 10 hours. But I also want the session to timeout if the website hasn't been used for 30 minutes. The FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie and Response.SetCookie part seems to work it just the session timeout that isn't.

Comment: All that's required is `<sessionState ... timeout="30" />`. If the user is totally inactive for 30 minutes, the session will expire. Bear in mind that the user must be *totally* inactive. Any request made to the website (AJAX included) will reset the timeout.

Comment: This doesn't work. I'm guessing its because the cookie exists, that overrides everything else and just logs the user back in.